# Can I insert an object into an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am pulling in a list of coordinates from our web server. I'm storing the whole list as an NSDictionary. While I am using the data (lat, long, radius, name) I would like to update the list of data with 1 or 2 more fields. Is there a way to insert these 2 items to the existing dictionary?

My only existing thought is that I would have to load the data into an NSMutableDictionary to allow additions and just create the new dictionary and overwrite the existing one with the new updated data. Hoping for a simpler or cleaner way rather than ghetto rigging it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think using an `NSMutableDictionary` would be *ghetto rigging* your solution. That's what mutable dictionaries are for.  In fact, this seems like much cleaner solution than allocating a new dictionary each time to handle your new set of data.

Comment: I am currently just storing all the data as an NSDictionary because I'm not adding anything to it, so it works fine. So there aren't multiple dictionaries or lots of allocations going on. Mainly looking for validation that the mutable dictionary is the path I need to take and there isn't anything better I could/should be using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought is correct, you have to create an NSMutableDictionary, as the NSDictionary can not be modified.

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDoc = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:doc];
```

If you have any immutable arrays or dictionaries in the NSDictionary, you might need a deep copy for modifcations.

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDoc = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, doc, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will have to look into the deep copy aspect for what I need to do. I need to be able to add items without destroying the existing data in them.

Comment: No data will be destroyed or lost. You can add new entries with setValue or setObject. You also don't need the deep copy if you just want to add entries.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The NSDictionary class declares the programmatic interface to objects
>   that manage ***immutable*** associations of keys and values.

So, `NSDictionary` is immutable--you may not add to it.  Using an `NSMutableDictionary` is not unclean or "ghetto rigging"...this is the whole purpose for an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for the negative rating. My question wasn't implying that using NSMutableDictionary was "ghetto rigging", just looking for a better solution, if any.

Comment: I'm confused...I didn't downvote your question.  Did you happen to downvote my answer? ;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No worries.

Comment: Ahh, but you didn't answer my question... ;)

Comment: Ummm... maybe. But it won't let me change it unless the answer changes. So maybe if there was a different answer, it would probably allow me to not be a quick to judgement d!ck. :)

Comment: Changed my answer a touch.  Don't worry about it--I can be one from time to time, too.

Comment: @BillBrasky let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2279/discussion-between-garlicfries-and-bill-brasky)

Comment: My pleasure.  If it helps, go ahead and accept the answer...or maybe @Patrick's was more helpful.  Up to you!

Comment: Holding out to see if anyone else posts anything different. I'll check back later and award one of you with the accept.